# ValidateRequest="false" not worked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I need send html. I get error(this machine transalate):

> Detected a potentially dangerous value of Request.Form, received from
>   the client (Description = "eqqdaqd  asda
>
> Description: The procedure of verification requests found potentially
>   dangerous client input value, the query processing is interrupted. 
>   This value may indicate an attempt to compromise the security of
>   applications, such as attacks by "cross-site scripting". To allow
>   pages override default scan request an application, see httpRuntime
>   configuration attribute to set the requestValidationMode
>   requestValidationMode = "2.0".  Example: . After setting this value, you can
>   disable request validation by setting validateRequest = "false" in the
>   Page directive or the configuration section .  However, in this
>   case are urged in the application explicitly check all the entries.
>   For more information, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=153133.

```
 public ActionResult Create()
        {
            this.ValidateRequest = false;
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Admin/News/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(NewsView model)
        {
            this.ValidateRequest = false;
            try
            {
               //logic

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

This controller is in the arena admin. I set in web.config

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could decorate your controller action with the [`ValidateInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateinputattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Create(NewsView model)
{
    ...
}
```

In your example you are setting the property inside the POST controller action but that's too late because validation is performed before invoking the action. Or if you want to disable validation only for a given property on your view model you could decorate it with the [`AllowHtml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[AllowHtml]
public string Description { get; set; }
```

Now you no longer need to decorate the controller action with the `ValidateInput` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [AllowHtmlAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)
Or if , you want to use `ValidateRequest` you should also set `requestValidationMode = "2.0"`